# Get inline style top from string regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input string like this:

```
let inputTest = `<div style="left: 474px; top: 550px"></div>`;
```

And I'm trying to get x from `left: x px` from above string.

I'm using regex like this one

```
console.log(inputTest.match(/\left:(.*)$/g));
// ["left: 474px; top: 550px"></div>"]
```

but it clearly start from word "left" but finish after entire string.

I want to start after 'left:' and finish before 'p' letter from px. So I will have only the number which will convert to its type (sometimes without space but will delete space after regex).

Comment: Why not use a DOM parser and get your CSS out as a property. If you're not in a browser environment you can use tools like [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Comment: It will work with string?

Comment: Thats the point of Cheerio, it parses HTML as strings and gives you a document you can navigate as you would in jQuery with `$('div')`.

Comment: inputTest.match(/left:(.*?)px/)[1]

Comment: @NagaSaiA please post it as answer.

Comment: @BT101  posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
inputTest.match(/left:(.*?)px/)[1]
```

code sample for reference

```js
let inputTest = `<div style="left: 474px; top: 550px"></div>`;

console.log(inputTest.match(/left:(.*?)px/)[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it, `left:.*?[\d]+`